# Как указать какой метод и из какого интерфейса реализовывается

Tags: java, ооп

Даны два интерфейса `Token`, `AbstractOperand`и один класс `Plus`
В классе `Plus` интерфейсы должны быть реализованы `class Plus implements Token, AbstractOperand`. В обоих интерфейсах есть `String toString()`, то есть я не понимаю какой из `String toString()` будет реализован, можно-ли как указать какой именною.

Comment: Это же интерфейс. Раз сигнатуры совпадают, то какая разница?

Comment: Будет реализован метод с сигнатурой `String toString()`. Доступен он будет при обращении через любой интерфейс.

Comment: Дело в том что почему-то реализовался только один метод

Comment: Как вы это определили? Покажите код.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный теоретический вопрос. :)

В принципе, интерфейсу все равно какой метод ему реализуют. Для интерфейса самое важное, чтобы все задекларированные в нем методы были реализованы.

Поэтому ответ на вопрос ТС :

"В классе Plus должен быть реализован **один** метод `String toString()` и этот метод будет использован в обоих интерфейсах"

---

Но, если продолжить рассуждения с точки зрения класса `Plus`, то возникает вопрос.

А что если нужно сделать **разную** реализацию для каждого из имплементируемых интерфейсов?

Т.е., из примера ТС, для интерфейса `Token` нужно возвращать строку "Token", а для интерфейса `AbstractOperand` нужно возвращать строку "AbstractOperand"?

Я вижу только одно решение данной проблемы.

В точках использования класса `Plus` для одного из интерфейсов сделать дополнительный класс - декоратор, реализующий данный интерфейс и содержащий в себе экземпляр класса `Plus`, вызывающий в методе `String toString()` дополнительный метод класса `Plus` (например `String toStringAbstractOperand()`), реализованный специально для этого интерфейса.

Может быть есть другие решения?